# Is true that $\int f(x)dx = o \left( \int g(x)dx \right)$

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $f(x)=o(g(x))$ (little-o)

I would like to know if is true that
$$
\int f(x)dx 
=
o
\left(
\int g(x)dx
\right)
$$

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ never change sign, I'd say yes. Otherwise, $\int_0^x g(t)\,dt$ could be frequently $0$ while $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ could be positive and strictly monotone (namely, $g(x)=\sin x+x\cos x$ and $f(x)=e^{-x}\lvert \sin x+x\cos x\rvert$).

Comment: thanks @G.Sassatelli, but i don't know if $f$ and $g$ never change sign

Comment: ok thanks @G.Sassatelli